# A friend wants to use my bank account to receive $50K and forward 65% of it to himself. Is this money laundering?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, money-laundering

A friend of mine says that 4 years ago he invested $500 in bitcoin and now the bitcoin company is paying off $50,000. He wants me to use my bank account to receive the money. He says he needs my routing and account number and for me to take out 35% and send him the rest. Mind you, he doesn't want to go through Western Union or Moneygram or any money transfer companies.

Is this money laundering?

Comment: Is this "friend" someone you know in person? This sounds like a scam.

Comment: If he is giving you 35% of money, just for your bank account, it seems fishy.

Comment: Why can't he open his own bank account? Run away.

Comment: Given Bitcoin prices in 2016 and 2020, I find it highly doubtful such an investment would yield a 100x gain. Assuming he bought at the lowest point in 2016 (~$430) and sold at the high point this August (~$12400), the $500 investment would only yield about $14500.

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: Consider: if everything is above-board here, why would someone pay you $17,500 to conduct a simple banking transaction that could be performed *at little to no cost* by the person themselves?

Comment: Remeber the old saying?  "With friends like these, you don't need enemies."

Answer (score 12):

If it's not money laundering, here's what will happen:

1. You receive $50,000 in your account.
2. You give your "friend" $32,500.
3. The deposit gets reversed. Your $17,500 disappears, and you are on the hook for the remaining $32,500.
4. You will be unable to contact your "friend" again.

Even the setup is fishy. The highest price for Bitcoin in 2020 was in August, just under $12,400. To recognize a 100x gain, he would have add to buy Bitcoin at $124. Bitcoin does not appear to have traded for so little since 2013.

Answer (score 6):

Think of below questions:

- Why don't your friend open a bank account himself and get the money
  himself. Why is he using your account for routing the money ? This
  seems too suspicious.
- Why your friend is giving you 35% of share, just for sharing your
  bank account details? This seems too suspicious.
- Banks are asked to report cash transfers > $10000, as per banking
  secrecy law to Treasury department. If your transaction is reported,
  do you have enough data points to clarify this to the Treasury?
- With your bank details being compromised, there are huge probability of identity theft happening.

From https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/moneylaundering.asp

> - Online banking and cryptocurrencies have made it easier for criminals
>   to transfer and withdraw money without detection.
> - The newest frontier of money laundering involves cryptocurrencies,    such as Bitcoin. While not totally anonymous,
>   they are increasingly    being used in blackmail schemes, the drug
>   trade, and other criminal    activities due to their relative
>   anonymity compared with more    conventional forms of currency.
> - The United States passed the Banking Secrecy Act in 1970, requiring    financial institutions to report certain transactions to
>   the    Department of the Treasury, such as cash transactions above
>   $10,000    or any others they deem suspicious, on a suspicious
>   activity report    (SAR).3 The information the banks provide to the
>   Treasury Department    is used by the Financial Crimes Enforcement
>   Network (FinCEN), which    can share it with domestic criminal
>   investigators, international    bodies or foreign financial
>   intelligence units

.

Answer (score 3):

You say “a friend”. Is it someone who you have known for many years? Who you meet for a beer or two once or twice a week? If not, it’s a scam. Your so-called friend will take $32,500 off you and you will never hear from them again. If yes, your friend has been falling for a scam himself. Tell him that you are not sending any money anywhere, and if he sends money, it will be gone.

Whatever it is, it is a scam, and whatever money is sent will be your loss. Whatever you receive, you won’t be able to keep.